# How to check the length of a table and the make an if condition with it and delete a row after?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table that i decrease one row each time it gets in a loop. How can check before the loop if the tables length is zero and delete the row i got after?

```
declare
l_temp number;
begin
insert into l_tem(select toy_id from toys);
 if l_temp > 0 then 
     for rw in (select toy_id from( select toy_id   
                                   from toys
                                    order by dbms_random.value)
                                 where rownum =1 )
       loop
        dbms_output.put_line(toy_id);
       delete from toys where toy_id(rw);
     end loop;
 else
 dbms_output.put_line('no more toys');
end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand *why* would you do it that way, instead of simply

```
delete from toys;
```

but never mind me.

You don't have to check anything. If table is empty, `FOR` loop won't run any *cycles* and simply step out of the loop.

If you *must* check it, then it is

```
select count(*) into l_temp from toys;
```

Also, you should reference values using cursor variable AND column name, e.g.

```
delete from toys where toy_id = rw.toy_id;
                                ---------
                                this
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was all i was looking for..